# Anyone know where the flow restrictor might be here? (Grohe Minta Touch)

Tags: kitchens, faucet, sink

I am looking to increase the flow rate of my kitchen faucet. It is currently around 1.75GPM. The faucet is a Grohe Minta Touch (original version). Attached below is a photo of the faucet diagram, any feedback would be great, thanks!

[image]

Comment: disconnect at #5 to see if flow is ok there

Comment: Check out 4.2 and 8.2.